# How can I tell if I am short-listed for postdoc position?

Tags: application, job-search, postdocs

I applied for a postdoc position whose application deadline was 24th June. When I contacted my potential mentor asking when to expect the results,

> **he thanked me for showing interest in applying for the position and told me that shortlisted candidates will be informed and the process will get completed by the end of July.**

Until now I have received no further information from the institution nor was any list published at the institute website. I contacted recently the institution through mail asking whether I am selected or not but got no reply.

So, considering what my potential mentor said, does his words mean that I am not selected for the position? Or should I wait? I am confused about what to do next, in order to know if I am selected or not.

Update: I have mailed my potential advisor as well as the institution about knowing the results of selection but there was no reply. Now i came to know by unofficial means that the applications are still being processed and the results are not yet decided.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think the answer you've got was pretty clear:

1. If you are short listed (for interview), you will be informed.
2. The process (including interviews and decisions) will be completed by end of July.

Typically, the shortlist is made within a week of the application deadline and interviews are conducted within another few weeks. The decision (of whom if any to make an offer to) is typically made immediately after the last interview and then it takes some more time before an offer is accepted.

In your case, this all fits nicely within the time frame of 5 weeks (24 June until end of July). So, if above *typical* scenario applies, then the fact that you haven't heard from them, implies that you were not shortlisted. But there may be other reasons, such as a delay in the process.

IMHO not informing those not shortlisted at the stage when the shortlist has been made (as is the case here) is a rather poor practice.

Don't be disheartened by a failed attempt to get shortlisted at a postdoc application. There are many applicants and you must expect to make several applications before getting there. You may ask them for feedback to improve your application (but most importantly: add publications to your CV).

Answer (score 5):

Keep in mind that your potential mentor is a very busy person- which is probably one of the many reasons they are hiring for a post doc.

The best thing to do is to wait till the end of the July, there is still about a quarter of the month to go. If you haven't heard anything then certainly feel free to touch base again to keep your name fresh in their head.